# How to test characters fall within unicode range

Tags: php, unicode

We have a news system that, because of localisation issues, allows characters from specific unicode ranges..

How can I test each character falls within range?

Example..

Here is one range

```
ExtendedLatin_c_iLowerAlphaChar = 0x00C0;
ExtendedLatin_c_iUpperAlphaChar = 0x01FF;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks